# How to detect a lost connection via chrome.hid API?

Tags: google-chrome-app, hid

I don't see a way to register a callback when a connection is lost in the [chrome.hid API](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/hid).  E.g. an `onConnectionLost` method.

How am I supposed to detect a user accidentally pulling the cable in the middle of a process?  Are we expected to poll, somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should star this issue: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=349473. When it's implemented you'll be able to do what you want.